# Access parent form from Admin 'Add another' popup in Django

Tags: python, django

Every object with a ForeignKey relationship to another gets for free a plus icon in Django admin interface. When this icon is clicked a popup window appears containing a form to create an new object of the type indicated by the ForeignKey relationship.

My question is, **is there a way to get the values of the popup's parent form fields?**, if not, would it be a way to hack the request that is called when the plus icon is clicked so the parent form is sent within the request object?

Comment: What do you want to do with those values?

Comment: @Claudiu I want to filter the values shown by a select box. Basically, I want to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) and use in the filter condition a value obtained from the parent form.

Comment: Nobody got a solution for this? I am in the same situation right now

Comment: @Xar could you check if the values of the popup's parent form fields are passed inside the GET obj of the request? for instance, request.GET['{FIELDID}']